# How to resolve special character exception issue in UTF8 byte code conversion in C#?

Tags: c#, utf-8

I am converting a string into UTF8 byte code,where as it is not accepting any special character and not converting it. so please help me to know convert these special char also in c#.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<Shipper>A & G VENLO BV</Shipper>");
```

Comment: I executed your line of code in a test method and it returned a byte array of length 33. Can you please provide more information about your problem ?

Comment: XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml("<Shipper>A & G VENLO BV</Shipper>");
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDoc.OuterXml);

Comment: xmlDoc.LoadXml throws a parsing error because ampersand has to be escaped in XML (regardless the text encoding) (https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax). So using xmlDoc.LoadXml("<Shipper>A &amp; G VENLO BV</Shipper>"); works fine.

Comment: @NarasimhaKolla that piece of relevant code belongs in the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not lead people astray. Your code throws a `System.Xml.XmlException` while parsing the XML.

The fact is that the string `<Shipper>A & G VENLO BV</Shipper>` is not well formed XML. The `&` symbol in XML must be escaped.

You have to create XML using the right approach:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement shipper = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Shipper");
shipper.InnerText = "A & G VENLO BV";
xmlDoc.AppendChild(shipper);
```

As a result, you will get the well-formed XML

```xml
<Shipper>A &amp; G VENLO BV</Shipper>
```

Now you can work with it

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(shipper.OuterXml);
```